# How to Match Mobile Contact List with Firebase register Contact List And Those match Contact How to Get Common Contacts from two List

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to get common contacts from two lists. One contact list is our mobile contract list and the second one is my Firebase register.

This is my Firebase Contact List:

[image]

This is my Mobile Contact Number List:

[image]

How do I get common Contacts in firebase and mobile Contact List and show in `UITableviewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are about 100 ways to approach this, but lets start with defining what you are after:

You are looking to find the intersection between two sets of data, which would be finding the common contacts between those sets.

Assuming that you know how to read the firebase node as well as the mobile contacts, let's start with a structure that contains the identifier (assume this is a phone number) and the contact name.

```
struct ContactStruct {
    var contact_phone = ""
    var contact_name = ""
}
```

then assume you have read in all of your Firebase contacts and mobile contacts, created strutures for each one and stuff them into two arrays.

```
var firebaseContactArray = [ContactStruct]()
var mobileContactArray = [ContactStruct]()
```

and then the rest

```
//take your contact arrays and create a set for each containing a common key
//   sting which will be the phone_number. Common key means it's something
//   that's common to both sets of data
let firebasePhones = Set( firebaseContactArray.map {$0.contact_phone} )
let mobilePhones = Set( mobileContactArray.map { $0.contact_phone} )

//now create a dictionary of key: value pairs of phone: contact.
//   We use this to look up the contact by phone number
let phones = zip(firebaseContactArray.map {$0.contact_phone}, firebaseContactArray)
let contactDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: phones)

//then find the intersection of those two sets. The resulting set will
//  be the common phone numbers
let commonPhones = firebasePhones.intersection(mobilePhones)

//now look up each phone in the dictionary to create a final array of common contacts
let commonContacts = commonPhones.map { (contactPhone) -> ContactStruct in
    let i = contactDict[contactPhone]
    return i!
}

//print the contacts name
for contact in commonContacts {
    print(contact.contact_name)
}
```

This should get you going.

You now have an array of common contacts that could be used as the dataSource for a tableView,

Keep in mind I've not implemented error checking or handled cases where the are duplicate phone numbers.

(this could also be condensed considerably using .map and .reduce functions and some other fancier code)

Comment: @Shamdhiman If the answer helped, be sure to accept it so it can help others as well.

Comment: Okay Thank You ............